# Could not connect to SQL Server database which is on my local machine using Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I try to connect to a SQL Server database using Python but I get this error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de données introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

This is my code:

```
import pyodbc
connexion = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17for SQL Server};""SERVER={ServerName};" "DATABASE={db};""UID={UID};""PWD={pwsd};")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"Data source not found and unspecified driver name"* Are you sure you have that driver name correct?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. I've checked the drivers.

Comment: Why not try just `"DRIVER={SQL Server};""SERVER={ServerName};" "DATABASE={db};""UID={UID};""PWD={pwsd};"`? Just so you know, the database name is still visible: `AvNextData`, in the database drop-down. You might want to hide that one too, next time.

Comment: Try 'DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=YourServerName;DATABASE=YourDatabaseName;UID=YourSQLOrDomainUserName;PWD=YourPassword;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;'

Comment: I've Checked and i've this message : 
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Ce serveur SQL n'existe pas ou son accès est refusé. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)")

Answer (score 0):

I've succeded to connect to the database. The issue was on server name. 
I've mentionned only the name without port. I've added the port and i'm now able to connect.
this is the new code :

```
server = '127.0.0.1,62181'#as the database is on my local machine
database = 'MyDB'
username = 'Username'
password = '123456789'
try:
    connexion = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
except:
    print("Connexion issue : ")
```